# problems with backbone.js and require.js in iOS webviews

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webkit, ios6, requirejs

I'm having some strange issues with our application not executing javascript

I have a web view thats loaded in an iPad app.
the page renders using require and backbone but something prevents the external libraries to execute.

the issues are with both d3.js and a jquery countdown plugin.

using firebug I dont get any errors but the countdown isnt starting.
same with d3 drawing some things but click functionality isnt working

im not sure if its a require issue or an iOS6 issue.
if it was a require issue i assume we'd get errors. but we dont.

anyone have any clues to what might be the issue?

main controller looks like this

```
/*global require: false */
/*jslint nomen: true */

// Sets up common libraries for all pages
require.config({
paths: {
    // Major libraries
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.8.2.min',
    //'jquery.mobile': 'lib/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min',
    //'jquery.mobile-config': 'lib/jquery.mobile-config',

    'underscore': 'lib/underscore-min',
    'backbone': 'lib/backbone-min',
    'fastclick': 'lib/fastclick.min',
    'easing': 'lib/jquery.easing.1.3',
    'countdown':'lib/jquery.countdown.min',
    // Require.js plugins
    'text': 'lib/text',
    'socket.io': 'lib/socket.io.min'
},

shim: {
    'jquery': {
        exports: '$',
        exports: 'jQuery'

    },
    'easing': ['jquery'],
    //'jquery.mobile-config': ['jquery'],
    //'jquery.mobile': ['jquery','jquery.mobile-config'],
    'fastclick': {
        exports: 'FastClick'
    },
    'countdown': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'countdown'
    },
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'socket.io': {
        exports: 'io'
    }
}
});


require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'views/main-view', 'view-controller','fastclick', 'easing', 'countdown'], function ($, _, MainView, ViewController, fc, easing, countdown) {
"use strict";

var mainView = new MainView();
$("body").html(mainView.render().el);

ViewController.initialize();
});
```

Comment: Did you get this figured out in the end? I have a similar thing... no errors in the browser, but in the iOS UIWebView, nothing. Not even seeing an alert from the first line from my main.js...

Comment: Turned out mine was a (really annoying) caching issue. Despite implementing every cache-busting feature I could find, it wouldn't load my new JS script unless I updated the index.html file... Now trying to figure out how to call a require.js module via stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString... :-/

Comment: Yeah, the issue for us was that the application were running multiple UIWebViews and we were using SVG graphics (through D3.js). SVG in multiple Webviews created strage unloggable errors. this was however in iOS6 and we have changed our solution since then